# Error trapping/Exception Handling

Tags: java

I have a basic grasp of error trapping by using try/catch blocks, however my method of trapping makes the user restart the program after an invalid character is inputted.

Can someone demonstrate how to make an effective error trap while allowing the program to run?

Code :

```
import java.io.*; //Input/Output command; this part is ESSENTIAL

class FindingTheSurfaceAreaOfAPyramid2
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));   //Loading the Text Box

        //Defining variables and string 'nicknames'
        String stringBaseLength, stringBaseWidth, stringTriangleHeight;  //named strings for organization's sake
        double convertToNumL, convertToNumW, convertToNumH, total1, total2, total3;   //'double' is nessesary for decimal answers as they commonly happen, using 'int' will round the result; inaccurate!
        //used in 'if' statements
        boolean realNumber = true;
        boolean realNumber2 = true;
        boolean realNumber3 = true;

        //First message and notice
        System.out.println ("Note: This program is compatible with ONLY rectangular based pyramids.");

        //Question 1: Units
        System.out.println ("First off, what unit is this pyramid in? (ex. cm, mm, in, ft. etc.)");
        String Units = myInput.readLine ();

        //Question 2: Length
        System.out.println ("1) Please enter the length of the base.");
        stringBaseLength = myInput.readLine ();
        try
        {
            Integer.parseInt (stringBaseLength);
            System.out.println ("Your base length is " + stringBaseLength + " " + Units + ".");  //this line is restating the the input as well as the unit of measurement
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            //If they catch anything other than numbers, it would tell the user
            System.out.println ("That was either a smart remark, a negative number or jibberish.");
            System.out.println ("As a consequence, you have to restart the program.");
            realNumber = false;


        }
        if (realNumber)
        {
            //Question 3: Width
            System.out.println ("2) Please enter the width of the base");
            stringBaseWidth = myInput.readLine ();


            try
            {
                Integer.parseInt (stringBaseWidth);
                System.out.println ("Your base width is " + stringBaseWidth + " " + Units + ".");

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println ("That was either a smart remark, a negative number or jibberish.");
                System.out.println ("As a consequence, you have to restart the program.");
                realNumber2 = false;

            }
            if (realNumber2)
            {
                //Question 4: Height
                System.out.println ("3) Please enter the height of the triangle face.");
                stringTriangleHeight = myInput.readLine ();

                try
                {
                    Integer.parseInt (stringTriangleHeight);
                    System.out.println ("Your triangle height is " + stringTriangleHeight + " " + Units + ".");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println ("That was either a smart remark, a negative number or jibberish.");
                    System.out.println ("As a consequence, you have to restart the program.");
                    realNumber3 = false;
                }
                if (realNumber3)
                {

                    //Converting the input to 'double' to express the answer(s) in decimal format
                    convertToNumH = Double.parseDouble (stringTriangleHeight);
                    convertToNumL = Double.parseDouble (stringBaseLength);
                    convertToNumW = Double.parseDouble (stringBaseWidth);
                    total1 = convertToNumL * convertToNumW;         //base area, length x width
                    total2 = convertToNumL * convertToNumH / 2;     //triangle area using sidelength 'length', base x height / 2
                    total3 = convertToNumW * convertToNumH / 2;     //triangle area using sidelength 'width  ,  base x height / 2

                    //Calculations and concluding sentences
                    System.out.println ("The area of the triangle with base length " + convertToNumL + " cm is " + total2 + Units + "^2.");
                    System.out.println ("The area of the triangle with base length " + convertToNumW + " cm is " + total3 + Units + "^2.");
                    System.out.println ("The base area is " + total1 + " " + Units + "^2.");
                    System.out.println ("The total surface area is " + (total1 + total2 + total2 + total3 + total3) + " " + Units + "^2.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
} //end
```

Comment: Code duplication is your enemy. Code duplication is your enemy. Code duplication is... Oh, wait. Jokes apart: please, extract the instructions of reading the input into a method... The error messages are funny, I appreciate that. But reading it 3 times is like listening to the same joke 3 times. Modifying is even worse...

Comment: You need to add a loop, something like `while(entryNotValid) { askForANumber(); }`, or `while(true) { askForANumber(); break; //only reached if the previous line did not throw }`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You posted a lot of code, but one pattern for continuing after an error is quite simple.  In pseudocode:

```
boolean validInput = false;
while (!validInput) {
    // Read some input from the user
    // If it's of the right format, set validInput to true
    // Else print an error message, and don't change validInput
}
```

The loop will continue to execute until the user enters something valid (or kills the program, of course).

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop it back till user enters realNumber

```
boolean realNumber = false;
        while(!realNumber)
        {

    BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));   //Loading the Text Box

            //Defining variables and string 'nicknames'
            String stringBaseLength, stringBaseWidth, stringTriangleHeight;  //named strings for organization's sake
            double convertToNumL, convertToNumW, convertToNumH, total1, total2, total3;   //'double' is nessesary for decimal answers as they commonly happen, using 'int' will round the result; inaccurate!
            //used in 'if' statements

            boolean realNumber2 = true;
            boolean realNumber3 = true;

            //First message and notice
            System.out.println ("Note: This program is compatible with ONLY rectangular based pyramids.");

            //Question 1: Units
            System.out.println ("First off, what unit is this pyramid in? (ex. cm, mm, in, ft. etc.)");
            String Units = myInput.readLine ();

            //Question 2: Length
            System.out.println ("1) Please enter the length of the base.");
             try
                    {
                        Integer.parseInt (stringBaseLength);
                        System.out.println ("Your base length is " + stringBaseLength + " " + Units + ".");  //this line is restating the the input as well as the unit of measurement
realNumber = true;
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                        //If they catch anything other than numbers, it would tell the user
                        System.out.println ("That was either a smart remark, a negative number or jibberish.");
                        System.out.println ("As a consequence, you have to restart the program.");
                        realNumber = false;


                    }
        }
```

Comment: You also don't need to be creating the `BufferedReader` in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor a code and remove duplication. 
Your code if you compare with the below is lot messier and easy to have errors in them.
Chop down the functionality as what is required and what can be re-used. Reuse should be top focus. How can you eliminate unnecessary steps?

```
 public class Test{

 static String Units=null;
 static BufferReader myInput 
 public static void main (String[] args){
 //Your Main function
 //Initialize the BufferReader and Read the UNITS
 // Sysouts with your questions
  convertToNumL=readDimension();
 // Sysouts with your questions
  convertToNumW=readDimension();
 // Sysouts with your questions
  convertToNumH=readDimension();

  //Your Calculations 

  }

  public static Double readDimension()
  {
      String temp=null;
      while(true) {

          temp=myInput.readLine();
          while(verifyDimension(temp)){

             return Double.parseDouble(temp);

          }

      } 


  }       

  public static boolean verifyDimension(String temp){

     boolean verify=true;

      try{

      Double.parseDouble(temp) ;

      }catch(NumberFormatException e){

        verify=false;

         //Your Statements
      }
       return verify;

  }            


 }
```

Comment: I don't necessarily understand this method, I should mention that I am in Grade 11 taking an introductory course to computer proraming/science.